# Set return response fields from webservice

Tags: android, response, webmethod

I am trying to use a webservice with a small database which consists of few fields namely name, age, sex, city.Now I have written a webservice which return either true or false based on name and returns to my activity.

Now here I need to output(ie..I need to show the other fields age,sex and city of that user) in various textviews.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
 <WebMethod> _
Public Function GetUserDetails(ByVal code As String) As String

    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    conn = ConnectionManager.GetConnection()
    conn.Open()
    Dim DsCheckUser As New DataSet()
    Dim newCmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()

    newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    newCmd.CommandText = "Select age, sex from userdetails where username='" & username & "' "

    Dim sqlda As New SqlDataAdapter(newCmd)
    sqlda.Fill(DsCheckUser)
    'Getting Back result from your DB.
    If DsCheckUser.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
    conn.Close()
    'Return address
End Function
```

And OnPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //Error status is false
        if(!errored){
            //Based on Boolean value returned from WebService
            if(codeStatus){
                            //Here I need to set the userdetails based on username and display them in each individual textview.
            }else{
                //Set Error message
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Username not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        //Error status is true  
        }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error occured in invoking webservice", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //Re-initialize Error Status to False
        errored = false;
    }
```

So based on codestatus whether it is true I need to get the remaining age, sex and city fields from my webmethod and display them in my textviews.

And here is my doInBackground:

```
 @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            //Call Web Method
            codeStatus = ScanWebService.invokeScanWS(editTextCode,"GetBarcodeDetails");
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: post your doInBackground method

Comment: @EmbattledSwag-Updated code

Comment: wait so do you need help getting the remaining information (age, sex, etc.), putting the info into `TextView`s or both?

Answer (score -1):

Edit 2: Just set text values to your TextViews.

Are you having any problems with this, if so post log cat?

Comment: @JanBo- Returning values is not my problem..I would like to know how do I set in my activity on PostExecute ?

Comment: Updated the answer, i misunderstood your question. Try with this code.

Comment: This is wrong. onPostExecute can access the UI thread (look at the vogella tutorial).

Comment: You are right i am talking gibberish, thats why the async is useful

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I think I understand what you need now.

### **In `doInBackground`**

From the looks of it, I would say your best bet would to firstly, make the call to the `WebMethod` and you can easily check if the returned value is `true` or `false`. If it returned `true`, you can make the second call to the `WebMethod` and save the returned value in a `String`. You can then parse the `String` and save the `String`s in fields that you declared either at the beginning of the `AsyncTask` or `Activity` (if you need the values outside of the score of the `AsyncTask` then obviously you declare them in the `Activity`.

### **In `onPostExecute`**

You can easily just take the fields that you stored the values from `doInBackground` and set the text to the `TextView`s there.

I don't have much experience with `WebMethod`s or whatever so I can't help you with that, however (though, it does seem like the `return address` line is unreachable code).